# Best practices for setting up initial Snowflake environment - Multiple URLs

Tags: architecture, environment, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to know how others have setup their initial Snowflake environment with considerations for DevOps and code deployments and their experiences in doing so.  Are people using multiple accounts/URLs to make DevOps and deployments easier or using one account and building out separate DEV, TEST, and PROD databases?  For example:

**DEV** = http://mydevaccount.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

- SourceSystem.Schema.Tables

**TEST** = http://mytestaccount.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

- SourceSystem.Schema.Tables

**PROD** = http://myprodaccount.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

- SourceSystem.Schema.Tables

Why or why not are you doing this?

In the past, I have setup environments under one account like:

**Single Environment** = http://mysnowflakeaccount.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

- **Dev**_SourceSystem.Schema.Tables
- **Test**_SourceSystem.Schema.Tables
- **Prod**_SourceSystem.Schema.Tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interesting that you refer to separate accounts as making DevOps easier in your question.  In my experience, it's easier to have everything in one account, and here's why.  If you use a nice structure in your RBAC model, there isn't a difference as far as isolating these environments (assuming you don't wish to have a separate IP Whitelist for your different environments, in which case this conversation is moot).  Meanwhile, if you then make sure that your scripts for DevOps, ETL, etc. are all referencing schema only (no database references), then migrating DDL, DML, etc. is as easy as it would be in separate accounts.  Meanwhile, one of the best features of Snowflake is Zero-Copy Clones for your testing lifecycle.  This is only available within a single account.  If you use separate accounts, you will need to copy your data from one environment to the next (duplicating or tripling your storage costs and a large time-consumer and credit-consumer).  Zero-copy clones allow for a near instant snapshot of your data to a different environment.

In my experience with many Snowflake customers, a single account is most common, but there are customers that use multiple accounts, as well.  It really depends on what is important to you.

Comment: Zero cloning is the main reason I've used one account in the past, data sharing also. Other members of the team I'm on think multiple URLs are better because code can't accidentally be pointing to wrong environments.

Comment: Leveraging RBAC correctly to completely isolate environments within a single account would also take care of any accidents.  Leveraging separate user logins by environment with perhaps a single role that allows for cloning and other migrations across environments can also work.

Comment: These are great responses, thanks for them.  Is there a good use case you've seen where Multiple Environments was clearly the correct choice?

Comment: Best example is whitelisting IP addresses where a customer limited application and user access via different IP ranges (dev VPN vs Prod VPN) which is only possible via separate accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you previously used single account approach for DevOps process but moved away from it.  Could you share which particular pain point may have triggered to change the approach?  Is it because of struggle to deploy objects between databases due to the changing database/schema names per environment?

Comment: Other members of our team have said multiple accounts gives better security isolation. Nothing can accidentally be pointing to the wrong environment. That is the main driver of this.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue when we first started working with Snowflake.

However, after discussions with our Sales Engineer, and lots of prototyping, we have now developed an approach which works well for us.

We have a single account with multiple environments per system.

For users, there are different roles which only allow access to the relevant environments - so the "dev" role only allows access to "dev" etc. 
It's slightly more complex than this, as there are multiple roles with different levels of access within each environment, but you get the idea - I hope!
In some of our systems, we enforce different user accounts for a single user so that the environments are as close to being separate as possible. This means that my development account cannot access roles which enable access to test or live.

Only the top level admins have access to the sysadmin (etc.) roles, and these are not default.

The approach means that we can almost instantly spin up multiple development environments - using live data, test data or dev data.

We do have multiple accounts, but each one runs a separate system (we have to physically partition some data in some instances) and we use data sharing to pass common data between the different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

We talked with the Snowflake Professional Engagement folks, and enlisted additional consultants when we started getting serious.
We ended up with an account for each environment.

Currently we use schemachange to manage deployments, Git for SC, and we have built out our own deployment processes (we don't do full-blown CI/CD at this time).
We will use zero-copy clones in the DEV account to do initial table development/scripting/etc, then it gets checked in to Git, where we deploy it to the actual DEV database.  So, if you're doing something in TEST_DB, we clone off TEST_DB_DEV, you do your work, check in the scripts, and we then deploy to TEST_DB in DEV.  Reason we do it that way is to make sure we have an audit trail of what has been deployed to what environment, and when.  Realistically, that may be too much, and we are evaluating other options.

Another reason we did things this way is because of connections in some of our ETL tools (we have a mixed bag of new and legacy, so it can be painful).  At least one tool would require us to go in and edit the actual commands because it forces us to use fully-qualified names, including the database, which would be a nightmare from both a change control and audit perspective.

Not saying we are doing it "right" (I mean, this is the database world, "it depends" is pretty much the only right answer), but this is our current process.  We have been working through ways to improve the process, but it's not easy.